# Bootstrap image is not responsive

Tags: css

I have the bootstrap full template (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full/) and I added a modal and a background image. When I resize it on browser it's responsive, when I go from phone on website the image is above the modal and it doesn't cover all the website.

I just edited the /css/full.css file to add the image.

How can i make it responsive on phone too? I accessed it on Chrome on two mobile devices and has the same problem.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to post your code, HTML and CSS for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "img-responsive" class to your img tag ()

So you the code should be like this:

```
<img src="your-source" class="img-responsive" />
```

You have the reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp

However provided code would make your question more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but I am reffering to background image, which stops above the modal.

My website looks like:

Background image
*blank*
Modal
*blank* to the end